# PHP ZipArchive 600

Tags: php, access, chmod, ziparchive

**PHP ZipArchive chmod 600 проблема доступа к файлу.**

Создается темповый (временный) архив, с правами **600** (-rw-------) из-за чего не может с ним работать.

**Вот как выглядит архив:**
archive_19-05-2020_18-33-51.zip.GIKCH2

Локально все отрабатывается и темповый файл я даже не вижу в процессе работы.
При переносе на сервер (linux), появляется проблема с доступом к архиву.

Собственно сам код, тут все стандартно.

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('upload/archive_19-05-2020_18-33-51.zip', \ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    throw new \Exception('Cannot create a zip file');
}
$zip->addFile('upload/file.txt', 'file.txt'); 
$zip->close();
```

При генерации других файлов, того же csv, файл получает права 644 и с ним можно спокойно работать.

Не могу понять в чем проблема, почему архив создается с ограниченными правами, хотя локально на (windows) все работает без проблем.

Comment: Сейчас путем экспериментов выяснил. Проблема в одном из двух, либо из-за того что версия php низкая (5.4) на используемом сервере, либо конфигурация самого веб сервера не позволяет.

Осталось выяснить в чем именно проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Если процесс не может создать файл в директории, значит у него нет на это прав. Это не ошибка кода, а настроек доступа к директории для пользователя, под которым запускается скрипт. Так же, скорее всего, если директории не существует, то она не будет создана и тоже будет ошибка.

Можете использовать [getStatusString](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ziparchive.getstatusstring.php) функцию для получения информации об ошибке.

Comment: Процесс создает файл. На моменте проверки $zip->open('upload/archive_19-05-2020_18-33-51.zip', \ZipArchive::CREATE все проходит по маслу. После, при попытке выполнить $zip->addFile создается временный zip файл с правами 600 и после этого ступор.  getStatusString вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Если архив создаётся, то доступ на чтение к добавляемому файлу есть? Да, и уточните если пробовали с полным (абсолютным) путём до файла, а не относительным. (либо с точкой - ./uploads/file.txt)